# UIBarButtonItem not showing up

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
@interface PartyListViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    UIBarButtonItem * toggle;

    //ProfileViewController *profileViewController;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *toggle;


- (IBAction)toggleAction:(id)sender;    // when the toggle button is clicked

@end
```

My interface builder looks like this:

[image]

I have added:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.toggle;
```

[image]

in my viewDidLoad, why doesn't the button show up?
If I create my button via code, it is there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your toggle button is not nil when assigned it to the rightBarButtonItem property!

Comment: you are right it is nil, but it doesn't make any total sense why it's nil as you can see from the IB above... I've had it there...........

Comment: You have to connect the IBOutlet of your class with the object in the Interface Builder.

Comment: didn't I do that in the pic above?

Comment: my only guess is because it is a tableviewcontroller and not a viewcontroller?

Comment: sorry, didn't saw the screenshots. A table view controller shouldn't be a problem. Are you using a UINavigationController to push the view controller or manually added a navigation bar? Otherwise the navigationItem is nil!

Answer (score 0):

I always create my barButtonItem via code....

I am very curious why you add **IBOutlet** at both place. Generally, I will add this keyword at where I declare the property.

Comment: oh yea...that one, I changed that... still

Answer (score 0):

I declared it as a tableviewcontroller and it should be a viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

do you have

```
@synthesize toggle;
```

getting called in your implementation? If you don't synthesize the object, it won't make getters and setters for you, so that may be why setting the rightBarButtonItem isn't working, as there is no getter for the toggle barButtonItem, so you're setting it to nil